# Pinch to zoom Ionic

Tags: angular, image, ionic-framework, zooming

I'm searching (but didn't succeed yet) a plugin or just a way for Ionic 5.4, used with Angular, that allows me to zoom and scroll an image on a modal view.

Something like this :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-viewer

but this one doesn't work anymore apparently.
Do someone knows something newer than that one, please!?

This is my configuration.

```
 Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (C:\Users\William Manzato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.22
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Photo Viewer plugin for pan and zoom support.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-viewer

```
this.photoViewer.show('https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg', 'My image title', {share: false});
```

Comment: Thank You, but as far as I know it doesn't works with local images, just online.. Am I wrong?

Comment: It works with local and online images both. For images present in your assets folder, just specify the location as the first argument. For images in device storage, get the absolute path. Use File plugin if you want to make a gallery kind of feature/app

Comment: Sorry I left with no internet.. Thank you so much, tomorrow I'll try with this and let you know

Comment: It works but File plugin is needed too to read local files.
Anyway, I've managed, Thank You so much again ;)

Comment: Happy to help :)